# SQL Server Client App

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, query-builder

I'm designing a database for internal use at my company that will store data that is produced by my team members. While SQL Server will be installed only on a single server machine, my team members will need to be able to access the data and run filter/select queries on it from their own terminals (for instance, search for the product from a specified brand that had the max score on a certain test). Obviously, I *could* design a web interface or C# app that did this, but I'm sure there's a client side app already out there that would allow this as well.

So is there? Even like a free Microsoft downloadable perhaps? I guess what I'm really looking for is a query builder of sorts. I remember working with Access back in the day and it had a nice GUI for making up nice little queries with max/min/average options and fitlers aplenty; that's what I'm looking for.

Also, table management (a la PHPMyAdmin) would be nice, but isn't necessary. The primary thing my team members need to be able to do is run select queries like the example I gave in the first paragraph. They don't even need to do insertions necessarily because I have a separate system set up for that.

Thanks!

P.S. I found [Acitve QueryBuilder](http://www.activequerybuilder.com) and [DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvisualizer.com/products/dbvis/) through Google, and they both look great. However, they both cost money as well. Is there a free alternative? Or, if not, are these two I found good query builders? Or are there other ones that are better?

Update: I just realized that while I can't install SQL Server Developer on all my team members' terminals, I *can* install the Express edition, which includes the management studio. I'm new to the software, but I'll mess around with that and see if it does what I want and post back...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answered yourself: SQL Management Studio Express Edition is the right tool for the job. Then if you need to restrict some access use the same tool as DBO and create the logins you need with the specific access restrictions to databases or objects involved in the project.

Just one detail, with SQL Management Studio Express Edition you cannot manipulate backups or copies of a database larger than 1 Gigabyte.

Comment: You say the express version cannot manipulate backups or copies of 1GB or greater... but I assume it an manipulate the original even if it's 1GB or greater, right?

Comment: OOPs I'm sorry, Is the SQL Express taht cannot manipulate more then 1 gig, not the Management Studio!

Answer (score 2):

You can install just Management Studio on their machines without having to install the SQL Engine. The download for it is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en).

Comment: Thanks! But you actually gave me a link to the 2005 version. The 2008 version is located here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b